# values of logged in users

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am making a friend system for a social networking kind of website.i have completed the search part now i am working on adding friends.so when a logged in user visits a other guy's profile he can send him friend request.so on clicking the button i am taking two parameter one is friend's id and other is user's id and passing it to the model.my tables are user_login for users and friends have 1)user_id1 2)friend_id1 and so on.so now i want to pass my data that i have recieved after clicking on the add friend button to the database and for that i have to join the two tables.i.e user_login and pivot table friends.so thaton clicking these id's get saved in that pivot table.just wanted someone to help me with the joining of tables.since it is showing me error.
my code for model is

```
public function display_followers($user_id,$friend_id)
{

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user_login');
$this->db->where('id',$user_id);
$this->db->where('id',$friend_id);

$this->db->join('friends', 'users_login.id = friends.user_id');
$this->db->join('friends', 'users_login.id = friends.friend_id');


$query=$this->db->get();
if($query->num_rows()>0){
return $query->Result();

}
else{
return false;


}
}
```

}

my code for controller is

```
public function followers(){
    $friend_id=$this->uri->segment(3);


    $user_id = $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];




$this->load->model('Main_Model');
$this->Main_Model->display_followers($user_id,$friend_id);
```

}

Comment: "it is showing me error" what error?

Comment: Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'user_login'

SELECT * FROM `user_login` JOIN `user_login` ON `users_login`.`id` = `friends`.`user_id` JOIN `user_login` ON `users_login`.`id` = `friends`.`friend_id` WHERE `id` = '6' AND `id` = '1'

Filename: models/Main_Model.php

Line Number: 36

Comment: @ElliotRodriguez this is the error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your error your join is wrong. You can see the statement being run in the exception details output.

`SELECT * FROM user_login JOIN user_login ON users_login.id = friends.user_id JOIN user_login ON users_login.id = friends.friend_id WHERE id = '6' AND id = '1'`

Should be something more like

`SELECT * FROM user_login JOIN friends ON users_login.id = friends.user_id AND users_login.id = friends.friend_id WHERE id = '6' AND id = '1'`

You know your model best, the above may not be the exact SQL statement you need but the join is clearly wrong

Comment: what does the 'and' statement mean??i mean how do we write code for this???

Comment: i had already figured out that i was supposed to use friends instead of user_login table.